# Is it possible to write literal byte strings with values larger than 127 in rust?

Tags: rust, byte, literals

I've noticed that in Rust, we can't use the byte notation for values larger than 128, that is

```
let x = "\x01\x17\x7f"
```

is fine since all chars are < 128, but

```
let x = "\x01\x17\x80"
```

will fail since `\x80` = 128.

Is there any way to still write string-like objects in that format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above 127 you enter the realm of Unicode and must use the `\u{codepoint}` escape sequence:

```rust
let x = "\u{80}";
```

Note however that 0x80 by itself isn't a valid byte in a UTF-8 string, so this turns out as two bytes:

```
let x = "\u{80}";

for b in x.bytes() {
    println!("{:X}", b);
}
```

prints

```
C2
80
```

If you instead need the value 0x80, you can't use a string and must use a byte slice:

```
fn main() {
    let x = b"\x80";

    for b in x {
        println!("{:X}", b);
    }
}
```

prints

```
80
```

Comment: Great! I didn't think to try pre-pending the `b` to the quotes! Cheers